# Wrong year value after conversion

Tags: c++, winapi, boost, uwp

I am converting date in format `yy/mm/dd` to `dd.mm.yyyy`. But it's returning wrong year value.

for example : 30/12/31 is expected to be **2030.12.31**. But it's returning **1930.12.31**.

I can't figure out why it's placing 1930 instead of 2030?

```
/// <summary>Gets a formatted date(gregorian date) as string from a date string with format - yy/mm/dd. </summary>
/// <param name="date">The date in format yy/mm/dd.</param>
/// <returns>The gregorian date in the format dd.mm.yyyy.</returns>
std::wstring GetFormattedDateString(const std::wstring& date)
{
    if (date.empty())
        return {};
    LCID lcid = LocaleNameToLCID(L"en-us", LOCALE_ALLOW_NEUTRAL_NAMES); //parse language tag to get locale ID

    DATE dt;
    VarDateFromStr(date.c_str(), lcid, 2, &dt);

    //get system time struct
    SYSTEMTIME st;
    ::VariantTimeToSystemTime(dt, &st);

    return GetDateFromTm(gregorian::to_tm(gregorian::date(st.wYear, st.wMonth, st.wDay)));
}
```

Comment: what is expected for 99/12/31?

Comment: It should be  31.12.2099

Comment: There's a difference between your expectations, and the designed behaviour of the function you called. It seems that your expectations don't match and the way forward is to align your expectations with those of the functions you use. If the functions don't do what you desire, you might need to write your own.

Comment: in Windows locale settings there's a field named *"when a two-digit year is entered, interpret it as a year between"* which defaults to 1930 to 2029, therefore year 30 would become 1930 and not 2030 https://winaero.com/blog/customize-the-taskbar-date-and-time-formats-in-windows-10/, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-date-system-format-or-two-digit-year-interpretation-aaa2159b-4ae8-4651-8bce-d4707bc9fb9f, https://excelsemipro.com/2011/06/regional-date-formats-in-excel/, https://www.howtogeek.com/247141/how-to-change-the-format-of-dates-and-times-in-windows/

Comment: @sohel14_cse_ju The key logic is related to the method GetDateFromTm you used, which is not from official library. So what is the logic under GetDateFromTm? You need to share this to others.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the logic this follows is similar to other languages - the parsing will return the year which fits in the range 100 back from today. Hence, if you parse 15/01/01, you will get 1/1/2015, but when you parse 30/01/01, you will get 1930/01/01.

What you do know however, is that the year's last two digits will match, so you can just manually fix the century. In pseudocode

```
fixed_year = 2000 + year % 100;
```

In your case I am using 21st century (2000) and I add the remainder from division by 100 from the year I got after parsing after. So what this does is that it cuts-off the century and replaces it with 21st century.